# Run a hadoop application written in java from php

Tags: php, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a web application and I need to run a hadoop jar from my web page in php.
I am quite new in web applications so I need a little help in starting my hadoop application written in java from php.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP app can [call](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) the command line to launch the Hadoop jar. Usually the command is like

```
$HADOOP_DIR/bin/hadoop jar [your jar file] [command line options]
```

Then, you can wait until the command returns.
I have used similar approach to launch Hadoop jobs from a Python web server.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked, but I still have a problem. I wrote the exec script in a php file, and from another page a make an ajax jquerry call to that php file which executes the script. If a use mozila browser the things works great, the script starts the hadoop aplication, but if I use google chrome the hadoop aplication doesn't start

Comment: I think that is a different question. It has to do with the client side calling your server side PHP script, not with how you will call Hadoop. BTW, could accept an answer, if you think it was correct?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer, if the machine is remote try:

ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_key.pub hadoop@server hadoop jar ...

if you are in AWS you can call elastic-mapreduce --list --active | grep -e "cloud name" to get the URL of your cloud (additional piping may be needed, but you get the idea)

Oh, don't forget to scp your jar first

Comment: Thanks a lot! My machine is not remote, but in the future it could be remote so it helps me!

Comment: Is there any posibility to print the hadoop errors in php when executing a job?